# Flow - Update picklist with label value, not API name

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, getpicklistvalues

I have a flow that is comparing the value of a text field (BillingCountry) to a picklist (Billing_Country_Name__C). If the text input is a valid Country picklist value, the flow should update the picklist to mirror the text field. The process I built seems to be working, however the only text inputs that seem to be taking are the API name and not the label of the picklist field. If I try to input "Mexico", I get an error **Billing Country Name: bad value for restricted picklist field: Mexico**. however it will take the API name "MX" and update the picklist to Mexico. How can I make this work so that "Mexico" = "Mexico" and not "MX" = "Mexico".